# Summarizing (and Maximizing) Data for Multi-Level Mixed Effect Model

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, mixed-models

I'm looking at the relationship of school district expenditure on the crime rate of cities/towns within that school district, specifically from 2000 to 2017. There's roughly 14,000 school districts (though it varies from ~15,000 in 2000 to ~13,500 in 2017. Crime data is the DV and is per city.

Covariates/fixed effects include pop density (city), pop (city), total law enforcement (city), proportion children living in poverty (school district or county), unemployment rate (county), voting history/diff between prop voted Dem. vs Rep. (county), per capita inc. (county), year, and student expenditure (school district)

The problem is that there's no neat nesting structure; unfortunately, students in one city might attend multiple school districts, and school districts don't fit neatly within counties (they overlap, so that one school district could serve multiple counties). In other words, there are roughly 13,500 school districts, but if you look at school districts as a function of county, there are ~19,000 school districts (so there's roughly 5500 overlapping school districts).

Without dropping NA's from my DV (crime), there are millions of values. Total, I have 133,000 cities/towns reporting crime during this period 17yr period. However, since cities/towns overlap with districts, I'll have a total of 1,220,000 observations (even after dropping NAs for cities/towns who didn't report crime).

I'm running a multi-level mixed model, and I'm wondering whether my model (and my grouping and summarizing structure of the data) incorporates the most amount of data and whether there is one random effects structure (see below) that is more principled than the other.

If I group by state, county, and city, and summarize by mean, I'll get city values of student expenditure, but they'll all be the student expenditure value within the county (though each will have different crime values). If I look at distinct values of state, county, and city for all years, I'll get 80300 distinct city/town values, which I then analyze in R through glmer (lme4).

I've run many models, but have used random effects structures (depending on whether or not the model is positive and can converge:

```
(year|CITY)+(1|COUNTY/STATE)
(1|CITY) + (1|COUNTY) + (1|STATE)
(year|CITY) + (1|COUNTY) + (1|STATE)
(year|COUNTY)
(1|COUNTY/STATE)

glmer.law_enforcement.type <- glmer(COUNT ~ CRIME + cent.log.pop + cent.log.pop.dens + year + cent.log.per.cap + diff.dem + cent.log.enforcement + cent.EXP_STUDENT + (year|COUNTY_ID), family = "poisson", control = glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE), total.years.v.p, na.action = "na.exclude")
```

Variables (in order) = type of crime; population; population density; year (numeric); per capita income; voting history; law enforcement; student expenditure (/1000).

Depending on my random effect structure, the model will mostly converge and be fine, but sometimes I'll get the following warning, so I'll change my random effect structure:

```
Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file:../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file:../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev,  : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

Comment: I would think you'd usually want to select random effects based on which characteristics of your data violate the assumption of independence rather than on which structures maximize your data. If there are notable dependencies by year and at the city, county, and state levels that you want to account for, you would need to include those in the model in whatever combinations reflect the underlying dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, @cgrafe--I think your first sentence is the rule of thumb, but my understanding is that when dealing with real-world data and of large magnitude, you can't always create the ideal random effects structures. Though I might be wrong on that (others please weigh in). I believe that my first structure is ideal, given repeated city correlation structure measurements over time. Then county-level data nested within state, but that model sometimes yields the above warning. I also might be wrong here.

Comment: Could you say more regarding the second half of your comment? I think that nesting county within state (1|county/state) should account for dependencies (of general redistribution of government funds, regions, etc). I'd think that (1|city/county/state) would be ideal, but that would be an enormous model. Do you have any thoughts on how I might better summarize the data? Perhaps by school district vs county? This is where I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I was just saying that I think it's more a matter of how the data were collected than any post-hoc finetuning. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified for more detail.